# Date format "D-#" or "D+#" with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'd like to display the date as a form like this `D-7` or `D+2`

I want to achieve it with `moment.js`.

I've found some reference from moment.js documentation, but they are not exact.

```
moment(expireAt).fromNow(); 
// it returns "in 7 days" but I want to see "D+7"
```

is there any easy way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `7` and `2` are *days*, you can use [`diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), perhaps with [`duration`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/).

For Example:

```js
function daysDiff(from, to) {
    const duration = moment.duration(to.diff(from));
    const diff = duration.as("days");
    return "D" + (diff < 0 ? String(diff) : "+" + diff);
}

console.log(daysDiff(
    moment("2019-09-01"),
    moment("2019-09-08")
));

console.log(daysDiff(
    moment("2019-09-03"),
    moment("2019-09-01")
));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```